# How to change the name of a role in JDA5?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Is it possible to change the name of a role in JDA. I don't seem to be able to find a method for doing this so I am starting to think it is not possible.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `RoleImpl` [seems to have](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/11c5bf02a1f4df3372ab68e0ccb4a94d0db368df/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/internal/entities/RoleImpl.java) a `setName()` method on it. Perhaps you an subcast a `Role` instance to `RoleImpl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As any entity update is done in JDA, you do it though the [manager](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Role.html#getManager()):

```java
role.getManager().setName("new name").queue();
```

Note that you can also do multiple updates at once:

```java
role.getManager()
  .setName("new name")
  .setColor(Color.RED)
  .queue();
```